Rendering artifacts in flat grease pencil scenes
I'm using Blender to create explanatory videos for highschool-level maths.
In this setting, I often have lines intersecting each other, and this results
in unexpected effects in the rendered images: The line in front seems
to cause a "reflection" on the line below.
To illustrate, here is an example of a circle over a grid
(which is supposed to represent the students' note paper).
In the areas marked pink the circle influences the
grid further than would be explained by anti-aliasing. By playing with
world lighting, I found that the color overlayed over the line is indeed
the world light.

I have already tried different variants (and a lot more over many hours
of tinkering and learning :))

The effect is the same, whether I use different layers within one grease pencil
object or different grease pencil objects arranged in 3D space.
(The latter would be the goal, because it facilitates animations.)

The same effect occurs both in EVEE and workbench engines and is
independent of sampling / anti-aliasing settings.

I plan to use an orthographic camera (and the above images are
with that camera), because I want 3D-objects to render the "math-book"-style.
The effect seems to be less pronounced with a "perspective" camera,
but it is still noticable, as the following example shows.



To test the hypothesis that some "light reflection" takes place,
I have placed a rectangle behind the drawing (in the 3D space) in
the upper-left area of the circle. My idea was that this rectangle would
perhaps "shield" the drawing from the background light and would prevent the
reflection of that light on the circle. And, in fact, there is a notable
difference in the rendered image in this area compared to the others,
though the effect is still present.

This is the setup in 3D space: the rectangle is a grease pencil
object behing the drawing:

What I would want to achieve as an ideal for my use case would be a
plain "one-to-one" rendering of the drawing, but I do appreciate that
this is not what Blender was made for. In fact, my last experiment
suggests that the "reflection" is the intended behaviour for Blender's
real use cases. (I'm new to Blender, but have a background in CompSci.)
Are there any tweaks in setting up the rendering and/or the scene that
would still reduce the effect some more? Thanks so much for any ideas!


Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

My first thought would be to create a plain "notebook" render that you can then reimport as a single image plane to use as the background, rather than doing everything with actual GP objects across the board. Break it into chunks and see what you can "bake down" to simpler objects and try that. I'm not sure it will fix it but it does seem like it's some kind of sampling artefact between where the GP curves "intersect" in an orthographic view. The technique I propose might avoid that.

I hope this is the right way to share via Blend-Exchange (thanks for that service!)


I edited your post (you can do that as well) and pasted that link into the body of your question. That's the official way to do it.

There are two things you can do to face the problem:
1 - enable Z Pass in the View Layer properties, as you should always do when rendering GP Objects.
2 - Play with the GP AntiAliasing threshold in the Render properties until you're satisfied with the result.

